# Button: minimal size

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a cancel button, which looks something like this: [image]

For the cross I'm currently using the letter 'x'.

Now I'm trying to reduce the empty space in the button, but I can't find a way to get rid of the vertical space.

Currently I have something like this:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CancelButtonTestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        Label someLabel = new Label("Some Label:");
        Button cancelButton = new Button("x");
        cancelButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em;"); /* 1 1 1 1 */
        cancelButton.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        someLabel.setLabelFor(cancelButton);
        gridPane.add(someLabel, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(cancelButton, 1, 0);
        gridPane.setHgap(5.0d);
        GridPane.setVgrow(cancelButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setHgrow(cancelButton, Priority.NEVER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 200, 50);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are you not using Insets?

I did `cancelButton.setPadding(new Insets(-5,0,-2,0));` and then I was able to remove the top/bottom space (that is available for Captial X). With capital X, I meant that if you will use X instead of x, you won't need any special padding but just Insets.EMPTY will do.

or to keep it dynamic you can even try `FontMetrics`

```
 FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(cancelButton.getFont());
cancelButton.setPadding(new Insets(-metrics.getDescent()*1.8, 0, -metrics.getDescent(), 0));
```

this code shall got after `scene.show()` to get the correct matrix.
[image]

Full code:

```
package test;

import com.sun.javafx.tk.FontMetrics;
import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CloseButtonTestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        Label someLabel = new Label("Some Label:");


        Button cancelButton = new Button("x");

         //cancelButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em;"); /* 1 1 1 1 */
        cancelButton.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        //cancelButton.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        someLabel.setLabelFor(cancelButton);

        Button cancelButton2 = new Button("X");

         //cancelButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em 0.083333em;"); /* 1 1 1 1 */
        cancelButton2.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        cancelButton2.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        someLabel.setLabelFor(cancelButton);
        gridPane.add(someLabel, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(cancelButton, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(cancelButton2, 2, 0);

        gridPane.setHgap(5.0d);
        GridPane.setVgrow(cancelButton, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane.setHgrow(cancelButton, Priority.NEVER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 200, 50);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(cancelButton.getFont());
        cancelButton.setPadding(new Insets(-metrics.getDescent()*1.8, 0, -metrics.getDescent(), 0));



    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: the style I'm using sets the padding to 1, 1, 1, 1 AFAIK
You're saying the recommended solution is to use negative values for padding? Why is this needed?

Comment: Setting the padding to empty doesn't look correct, neither with small x nor with capital X.

Comment: I can share the image, that works fine for me. I have uploaded the image with my changes.